# Guessing a value for hyperlane (Soft Margin Classifier)

Tags: machine-learning, math, geometry, svm

With intercept being 2, I want to guess the value for the hyperplane in the image in the below link.

https://ibb.co/vB6NszN

[image]

I didn't quiet get the whole concept of it and I don't know how to guess a value for hyperplane. Any help is appreciated.

Note:I'm sorry I'm not able to share images in my question yet.

Comment: What do you mean 'guess a value for hyperplane'? Is this question programming-related? What is your code? What have you tried so far? Please add more details to your question

Comment: Well the whole question is in the link https://ibb.co/SNDkLV1 to be exact. And I'm trying to solve the g part @Proko

Comment: please do not post [the same question twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65544640/2521214). As I mentioned in the duplicate your image is without context. The therms are not standard geometry ones so they need some explaining. Also core of your question is in image which is off site and needs clicking (many users will not do that) and also question text in image is not a good idea as it can not bee searched hence no answers yet as the users that would able to answer either dismiss it or not even see the question for the same reasons.

Comment: btw: Are you searching for a hyperplane that would best fit the "gap" between ND points in your dataset? or divide it to some ratio or property? or what ...